# JQuery UI Tabs inside Dialog - Load Tab content based on Dialog title?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am cloning a JQuery UI Dialog with nested tabs.

```
<div class="dialog">
            <div id='tabs'>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#presentations">Presentations</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#outcomes">Learning Outcomes</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#conditions">Core Conditions</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div data-type="presentations" id="presentations"></div>
                <div data-type="outcomes" id="outcomes"></div>
                <div data-type="conditions" id="conditions"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and

```
var dialogs = $( ".dialog" ).clone().appendTo('body').removeClass( 'dialog' ).dialog( {
                                title: dialogName,
                                width: '383'
                            } ).tabs();
```

On clicking a tab in the cloned Dialog, I want to load content to that specific tab using Ajax based on the title of the parent Dialog.  E.g. something like below (which is not working...):

```
    $( '.ui-tabs-tab' ).click( function () {
                if ( $( this ).data( 'type' == 'outcomes' ) ) {
                    $.ajax( {
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "scripts/get_learning_event_outcomes.php",
                        data: {
                            learning_event: $(this).parent().dialog( "option", "title" ),
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            $( this ).html(data);
                        }
                    } );
                }
            } )
```

How can I do this?  Have I got the click wrong on the Tabs??

**UPDATE**

OK, I have the cloned Dialog and nested Tabs working OK, except for loading content into specific tabs.
Rather than assigning a unique ID to the tab divs, I would like to access the relevant div through the DOM, i.e related to the clicked li.ui-tabs-tab:

```
<div class="dialog">
            <div class='tabs'>
                <ul>
                    <li data-type="presentations"><a href="#presentations">Presentations</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-type="outcomes"><a href="#outcomes">Learning Outcomes</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-type="conditions"><a href="#conditions">Core Conditions</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div id="presentations" class='presentations'></div>
                <div id="outcomes" class='outcomes'></div>
                <div id="conditions" class='conditions'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and

```
$(document).off("click").on('click','li.ui-tabs-tab',function () {  
        if ( $( this ).data( 'type' === 'outcomes' ) ) {
     $.ajax( {
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "scripts/get_learning_event_outcomes.php",
                        data: {
                            learning_event: $(this).parent().dialog( "option", "title" ),
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            $( '#outcomes').html(data);
                        }
                    } );
        }
    });
```

Replacing `$( '#outcomes').html(data);` with the associated div in Tabs.  Any ideas?  Note that there may be multiple Dialog and nested Tabs widgets open at once, so the targeting of the Ajax content needs to be specific to the clicked tab...

**UPDATE 2**
I now have the code below and just need to identify the tab for Ajax load data in the cloned Dialog/Tabs.

```
var dialogs = $( ".dialog" ).clone().appendTo( 'body' ).removeClass( 'dialog' ).dialog( {
                                title: dialogName,
                                width: '383',
                                open: function ( event, ui ) {
                                    $.ajax( {
                                        type: "POST",
                                        url: "scripts/get_learning_event_outcomes.php",
                                        data: {
                                            learning_event: $( this ).dialog( "option", "title" ),
                                        },
                                        success: function ( data ) {
                                            $(this).find('.outcomes').html(data);
                                        }
                                    } );
                                }
                            } ).tabs();
```

i.e., `$(this).find('.outcomes').html(data);` Note  `$('.outcomes').html(data);` works, but is not specific to the cloned dialog...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
var dialogs = $( ".dialog" ).clone().appendTo( 'body' ).removeClass( 'dialog' ).dialog( {
                                title: dialogName,
                                width: '383',
                                open: function ( event, ui ) {
                                    var el = $(this).find('.outcomes');
                                    $.ajax( {
                                        type: "POST",
                                        url: "scripts/get_learning_event_outcomes.php",
                                        data: {
                                            learning_event: $( this ).dialog( "option", "title" ),
                                        },
                                        success: function ( data ) {
                                            el.html(data);
                                        }
                                    } );
                                }
                            } ).tabs();
```

Answer (score 3):

*(Revised answer)*

Easy way... is like [this](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax):

> Fetch external content via Ajax for the tabs by setting an `href`
>   value in the tab links.

Or if you don't want to do it that way, then you can use the [`beforeActivate`](https://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-beforeActivate) and [`create`](https://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-create) events for jQuery UI Tabs, like so:

[Demo on CodePen](https://codepen.io/5ally/pen/gVBZKe/left/?editors=0010)

```
function loadPanelContent( panel, tab ) {
  // Run your AJAX here. See the demo for an example.
}

// Clone the dialog.
$( '.dialog' ).clone()
  .dialog({
    title: dialogName, // I assumed `dialogName` is defined somewhere.
    width: 383
  }).tabs({
    // Fired before a panel is opened.
    beforeActivate: ( event, ui ) => loadPanelContent( ui.newPanel, ui.newTab ),

    // This is for the first/default active tab/panel.
    create: ( event, ui ) => loadPanelContent( ui.panel, ui.tab )
  });
```

### UPDATE

Updated the demo and the above code. And...

> I can't use the first option for cloned tabs

Why not?

You can dynamically change the `href` value:

```
$( '.dialog' ).clone()
  .find( 'a[href="#outcomes"]' )
    .attr( 'href', 'scripts/get_learning_event_outcomes.php' ) // change the href
  .end()
  .dialog({
    title: dialogName,
    width: 383
  }).tabs();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use the first option for cloned tabs and the second looks overly complex for this purpose.  I have updated the OP with an updated example.

Comment: Alright then, but the answer is for this part: "On clicking a tab in the cloned Dialog" in the question.